# monitor wlan status and reconnect if disconnected

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I want to preface this question by saying I'm not even sure this is the actual problem I'm having but it's the only thing I can think of offhand.

I built a small IoT device that includes its own web server so I can control it (just inside the house, it's not exposed outside my network). From time to time it will disappear from the network, only to reappear with a different IP address, and I have no idea what that address even is unless I run `nmap` to find devices that have a specific port open. I thought I could fix this by having the device ping a central service that keeps track of when any given device came online and the IP address the device reports that it's using, which is fine for when the device boots, but not if it reconnects (which could be any number of reasons - bad signal, refreshing DHCP lease, etc.). My next thought was to monitor the network connection somehow using `uasyncio` (basically every 30s checking if we're connected and what the current IP address is; if disconnected, reconnect; if the address is different than what it was the last time we checked, ping that service again and report the new IP).

So first question: is this a dumb idea and I'm just overlooking something simple?

Second question: is there some sort of callback mechanism on `network.WLAN` that I can observe changes in connection status or IP address?

I did write up a class that (should?) do this but I'd rather not roll my own...

Comment: If you are the manager of your router- you can set a static IP address by MAC address. I would try to solve this issue that way, not by changing micropython code. 
Another option Static IP https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=2378